# Symfony2 callback using many form fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, callback

I've been wondering if it is possible to validate many form fields using a single callback function in Symfony2.
In my project I'm using a REST API and I wanted to send username and password fields in order to check if they are valid. I don't want to create an Entity class for that.

Answer (score 0):

See the [ValidatorInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ValidatorInterface.php) definition — it has several methods you could use to validate particular properties or values using the `validator` service.